# Run async/await function inside a reduce Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await, reduce

I need to fetch values from another API using the `guid` inside this particular array, then group them together (hence I used reduce Javascript in this case)
However, I could not get those values `sumEstimatedHours` and `sumWorkedHours`  as expected. Can someone suggest a method please?

```
export const groupProjectsByPM = (listOfProjects) => {
  const dir = "./json";
  const estimatedHours = fs.existsSync(dir)
    ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./json/phases.json", "utf-8"))
    : null;
  let sumWorkedHours, sumEstimatedHours;

  const groupedProjects = listOfProjects?.reduce(
    (
      group,
      {
        guid,
        projectOwner: { name: POName },
        name,
        customer: { name: customerName },
        deadline,
        calculatedCompletionPercentage,
      }
    ) => {
      listOfProjects.map(async (element, index) => {
        // const element = listOfProjects[index];
        sumWorkedHours = await getWorkhoursByProject(element?.guid).then(
          (res) => {
            return res.reduce((acc, cur) => {
              return acc + cur.quantity;
            }, 0);
          }
        );

        const filteredEstimatedHours = estimatedHours.filter(
          (item) => item.project.guid === element.guid
        );

        sumEstimatedHours = filteredEstimatedHours.reduce((acc, cur) => {
          return acc + cur.workHoursEstimate;
        }, 0);
        group[POName] = group[POName] || [];
        group[POName].push({
          guid,
          name,
          POName,
          customerName,
          deadline,
          calculatedCompletionPercentage,
          sumEstimatedHours,
          sumWorkedHours,
        });
        return group;
      });

      return group;
    },
    []
  );

  return groupedProjects;
};
```

Comment: https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/ helped me to understand nuances of async functions in loops

Comment: Just don't use `reduce` for grouping. Use a regular loop and the `async`/`await` will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

here is an example of async/await inside reduce:

let's assume that we have an array of numbers

```
const arrayOfNumbers = [2,4,5,7,6,1];
```

We are going to sum them using reduce function:

```
const sumReducer = async () => {

  const sum = await arrayOfNumbers.reduce(async (promisedSum, num) => {
    const sumAcc = await promisedSum
    // any promised function can be called here..
    return sumAcc + num
  }, 0)

  console.log(sum)
}
```

So the trick is to remember to await the accumulator inside the reduce function

```
export const groupProjectsByPM = async (listOfProjects) => {
  const dir = "./json";
  const estimatedHours = fs.existsSync(dir)
    ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./json/phases.json", "utf-8"))
    : null;
  let sumWorkedHours, sumEstimatedHours;

  const groupedProjects = await listOfProjects?.reduce(
    async (
      promisedGroup,
      {
        guid,
        projectOwner: { name: POName },
        name,
        customer: { name: customerName },
        deadline,
        calculatedCompletionPercentage,
      }
    ) => {
      listOfProjects.map(async (element, index) => {
        //accumulator in your case is group
        const group = await promisedGroup;

        // const element = listOfProjects[index];
        sumWorkedHours = await getWorkhoursByProject(element?.guid).then(
          (res) => {
            return res.reduce((acc, cur) => {
              return acc + cur.quantity;
            }, 0);
          }
        );

        const filteredEstimatedHours = estimatedHours.filter(
          (item) => item.project.guid === element.guid
        );

        sumEstimatedHours = filteredEstimatedHours.reduce((acc, cur) => {
          return acc + cur.workHoursEstimate;
        }, 0);
        group[POName] = group[POName] || [];
        group[POName].push({
          guid,
          name,
          POName,
          customerName,
          deadline,
          calculatedCompletionPercentage,
          sumEstimatedHours,
          sumWorkedHours,
        });
        return group;
      });

      return group;
    },
    []
  );

  return groupedProjects;
};
```

Best of luck ...

Comment: I made a small correction and applied the solution on your code ..